# Equalise the count of characters in a string by removing one character at a time

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I want to **equalize the frequency of character in a string by doing minimum number of operations**. Here one operation is "removing one character at a time".
String consist of lower case English alphabets.

**E.g. Given string "abcdab"** , here I can remove one 'a' and one 'b' thus 2 operations will be required and frequency of each character will be equal then.

Also I can completely remove a character **e.g. 'aaaabbbc'** in this I can remove one 'c' and one 'a' to make frequency equal.

I am unable to find the logic.Can anyone suggest the algorithm?

Comment: I am not able find out how to do this in minimum number of steps.

Comment: I have found the frequency, and tried to equalize the frequency which is most common, but that approach is not working

Comment: Calculate how many single "removing one character at a time" and use this as an upper bound for a search.

Comment: In what context do you need this? Or is it simply homework?

Comment: I encountered this question few days back on a coding site.

Comment: In the second example I have given, I have calculated frequency as 4,3,1. Now how can I approach to equalize these numbers. Can you elaborate more as I am novice programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first describe a quadratic solution, and then we will make it O(n log n)

Convert your string to a list of frequencies:

```
4, 3, 1
```

Then, observe that the final frequency that all the characters will share will be equal to the one of the existing frequencies. In other words, at the end the frequencies will either be 4, 3 or 1. In a loop try each of the frequencies. Once you fixed the frequency, it is easy to compute number of steps it will take to make all characters to have either that frequency or zero. It will be something along the lines of:

```
res = BIG;
for (int idxOfFreqIWant = 0; idxOfFreqIWant < n; ++ idxOfFreqIWant) {
    int cur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i) {
        // if element occurs >= the freq, we remove characters to make it equal to freq
        if (a[i] >= a[idxOfFreqIWant]) cur += a[i] - a[idxOfFreqIWant];
        // otherwise we have to remove all occurences
        else cur += a[i];
    }
    if (cur < res) res = cur;
}
```

Now, this is obviously quadratic. You can make it O(n log n), I will only describe the high level idea: you sort all the frequencies in descending order, iterate from left to right, and maintain the sum and count of frequencies you've seen so far. Now as you fix a frequency, you know the sum and the count of all the characters that have higher frequencies, and sum and count of all the characters that have lower frequencies, from that you can compute the `cur` without iterating over all the elements, hence doing one update in constant time. The total complexity will be `O(n log n)` to sort + `O(n)` to do the pass.